# Posting elements generated by JS (JQuery) to a PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, forms, posting

so I'm writing this form for teams and doing this 'add player' function where you enter a player name in a textfield, check a box for medically ok and click a button which then appends the name to a div above, adds the value to an array and clears the textfield below, like so:

```
<script>
     var players = New Array();
     function addPlayer(){
          $('#players').append($('#addPlayerField').val());
          var playerInfo = New Array($('#addTermCheckbox').prop('checked'),$('#addPlayersField').val());
          addingTerms.push(playerInfo);
          $('#addPlayerField').val('');
       }
</script>
```

Whats the best way to post the final array to a php script?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use JQuery's ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: 'players='+$.toJSON(players),
  success: function (data) {}
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

What do you meen with posting the final array to a php script? If you want to send the information to a php script try looking the jquery documentation about ajax (to send the data to the php file without reloading the page) and json (to convert your array into a text form and then beeing able to rebuild the array in the php file)

Comment: nothing like .load or some, its a html form and I want to be able to do a foreach on the array one a user submits

Comment: To send the data, you should use an ajax request, documented in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ , using the POST method and a JSON encode library (example: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php), you cand send the entire array to php in a nice format:
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: 'playerData'+array2json(playerDataVar)
  success: function (data) {}
});

And retrieve it using php on the server side, http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean sending the array elements to a PHP script?  in JSON and use json_decode() in PHP. Depending on what information you need, json_decode() can either convert to an associate array, or objects. Use [JQuery-Json](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) which will add the ability to encode JSON in your code.